# Make an overlay to cover height of another element

Tags: jquery, css

I have a number of elements on the screen that I need to cover with overlays. Elements are of different sizes and can be resized during the lifetime of the page.

I was able to use this CSS to place overlays where needed, except that 100% height does not work:

```
.upgrade {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Is there any way in CSS to set one element to completely cover another. If CSS is not an option, my fallback plan is to use jQuery/JavaScript to set the initial height and then track the resize event. I hope that's the right course of action...

But, I really wish the 100% height issue could be solved with CSS. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your HTML. Where is the overlay element situated? Is it within the same container as the underlying element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the absolutely positioned element within the element it should cover, in your HTML. Then make the element you want to cover `position: relative;`.

After that you modify the CSS of the absolutely positioned element to:

```
.upgrade {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

The absolutely positioned element will now be positioned in relation to the closest parent that has relative position. So top, bottom, left, and right will be in relation to that element instead of the entire document - thus you should cover the entire element.

**Update:**

More about absolute positioning is available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). CSS-Tricks also has [a short article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) on this topic.